# Como relacionar un modelo en Django con el mismo?

Tags: django-models

Necesito relacionar un modelo en Django con el mismo, sin que el campo de la relación sea obligatorio llenarlo. Gracias por adelantado.

Ejemplo:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(verbose_name="Codigo")
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre")
    direccion = models.CharField(verbose_name="Direccion")
    gerencia = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=(u"Cliente"), related_name="cliente_subordinacion")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.codigo, self.nombre)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.codigo, self.nombre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés utilizar `null=True` (para poder guardarlo como `Null` en la base de datos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null) y `blank=True` (para que no te lo pida en la validación de los formularios de Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#blank)

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(verbose_name="Codigo")
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre")
    direccion = models.CharField(verbose_name="Direccion")
    gerencia = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=(u"Cliente"), related_name="cliente_subordinacion", null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.codigo, self.nombre)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.codigo, self.nombre)
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución